# Add action in jenkins project page

Tags: maven, jenkins

I would like to add an action in my jenkins project's page. This action must be able to upgrade my project version (in my pom.xml file) and make a commit to the SVN. It will be triggered by a click to the action's button.

Anybody could explain how to implement a new action like this ?

Thank you

Comment: First I would suggest to make those steps are needed on plain command line ...afterwards you can look how to do that in Jenkins...

Answer (score 0):

Create a Jenkins job for this and execute it using it's *Run* button. That's what Jenkins is made for.